# Using CFEngine to copy a directory tree except certain files

Tags: cfengine

I'm using CFEngine to deploy apache sites. So, I have a 
repository setup and my agents are copying files from it.

The trouble is when I'm editing my files using vim, it creates 
swap files. And they are copied to the server, which is bad 
because everytime I'm firing up my editor, all these machines 
download the swap files.

**The big problem** is that this triggers the restart of apache.

TLDR: how do I tell CFEngine to ignore files matching `\..*\.swp` ?

Here's what I have right now:

```
files:
        "/etc/apache2/sites-available/"
                handle => "apache-sites-available",
                depends_on => { "apacheinstall" },
                create => "true",
                copy_from => secure_cp("/srv/repos/apache2/conf/sites-available/","$(sys.policy_hub)"),
                depth_search => recurse("inf"),
                classes => satisfied("apachemustrestart");
        "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/"
                handle => "apache-sites-enabled",
                depends_on => { "apacheinstall", "apache-sites-available" },
                create => "true",
                copy_from => secure_cp("/srv/repos/apache2/conf/sites-enabled/","$(sys.policy_hub)"),
                depth_search => recurse("inf"),
                classes => satisfied("apachemustrestart");
                # promise_repaired => { "apachemustrestart" };

services:
        "apache2"
                handle => "apacheenable",
                depends_on => { "apache-sites-enabled" },
                service_policy => "start";

        apachemustrestart::
        "apache2" 
                service_policy => "restart";
```

Here's the `satisfied` class

```
body classes satisfied(x)
{   
      promise_repaired => { "$(x)" };
      # persist_time => "0";
}
```

**Edit:** My post was not precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about the CFEngine configuration - I haven't worked with that.  You can work around your issue by telling vim not to create additional files during editing.

*set nobackup*

*set nowritebackup*

*set noswapfile*

Comment: That would be a last resort option. I'm also trying to find a way to ignore some files because I want to use git to push these files into the `/srv/repos/` directories.

Comment: I know I can use gitignore to ignore the swap files too. But, regardless, I've been looking for a way to ignore files for some days now.

Comment: It looks like the old file class had options to symlink, ignore, exclude, and include options.  Apparently there was a global ignore directive at one point.  Not sure if it was removed or if it's just no longer advertised... http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/cfengine/html_node/cfengine-Reference_58.html

Comment: You could also probably use a transform to delete the files in question.  ( That's my idea of a TRANSFORMATION! ) https://docs.cfengine.com/latest/examples-example-snippets-basic-file-directory.html ( "Locate and transform files" transformer => )

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but provided no one has given an answer to this I will:

```
bundle agent filecache {
    files:
        myclass::
          "/etc/apache2/sites-available/"
            copy_from   => mycopy("/your_path","$(sys.policy_hub)"),
            depth_search => recursive_exc_swp;
}

body copy_from mycopy(from,server) {
      source      => "$(from)";
      servers     => { "$(server)" };
      purge       => "true";
      stealth     => "true";
      preserve    => "true";
}

body depth_search recursive_exc_swp {
    depth => "inf";
    exclude_dirs => { "\.swp" };
}
```